# Arrays and DirectX API

Tags: c++, arrays, directx-11

I want to create an array of D3D11_INPUT_ELEMENT_DESC for passing to the CreateInputLayout function.

Within my own program I am using a vector to build up and store the D3D11_INPUT_ELEMENT_DESC.

Knowing the DirectX API doesn't accept vectors, how should I approach creating a dynamically sized array that I can pass to DirectX?

Comment: If you have a `std::vector` you don't need to bother with memory management. Also the smart pointer classes you mention will do the memory management for you, you don't need to call `delete`.

Comment: An `std::vector` is a datatype that can be returned from a function, just like e.g. a string. Use that.

Comment: Could you please delete anything in the question that hasn't to do with the problem that you want to ask for?

Comment: I'm going to be completely honest with you guys, the answers given make this a very stressful place to ask questions. I specifically stated that I am using the DirectX API, which does not accept vectors as arguments, yet everyone jumped immediately on the "use vectors instead" answer. I was then told that my question was wrong.

Comment: Mark - can't comment on the original form of your question, since I didn't see it.   But if v is of type std::vector<X> then the expression &v[0] gives a pointer to the first element of a dynamically allocated array within the vector that can be passed to API function which expects a raw pointer to the first element of an array.  The only thing to watch is resizing the vector to the required size BEFORE passing &v[0] to the function.

Comment: Thankyou Rob, that is an incredibly helpful answer.

Comment: No worries. Just be patient with folks here :-)   When I joined recently, I also found there are a lot of abrupt answers because there's a lot of "assumed knowledge" here, which can be stressful for anyone who doesn't have that knowledge.  Take your time with it.  Take comments like those above as hints to search (e.g. in this case, you might google for "c++ vector" based on comments above).  What you find might not completely address your concerns, but it'll usually help you by clarifying a bit - and give you a basis for finetuning your question. Persistence helps.

Comment: I will always try and be clear with my question. In this case I made it clear that I wanted to use an array because the DirectX API doesn't accept vectors, and I was still told to use a vector by several people. Even the tiniest amount of common sense would have resulted in the conclusion that I didn't know how to access the underlying array of a vector, and the answer would be "here is how you access the array under a vector".

A lot of this can be solved if people look a little deeper than the question and consider "why could this person be asking this question?"

Comment: ``std::vector<D3D11_INPUT_ELEMENT_DESC> v;``  followed later by ``device->CreateInputLayout( &v.front(), v.size(), ... );``

Comment: &v[0] and &v.data() also work, thanks for that!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In C++ you can (mostly), and hence should, avoid to deal *directly* with dynamic memory allocation and/or deallocation, since library provides appropriate support via container classes (`std::vector` etc) and `std::unique_ptr`. Not dealing with this directly by yourself has the great benefit that your code is unlikely to suffer from memory leaks, dangling pointers (though here some care is required), and should be exception safe.

However, occasionally, you must use an API that doesn't know about the beauty of C++ but only accepts raw pointers. Typically, this is to access a C-style array of data together with its size, i.e.

```
void C_style_func(void  *ptr_to_first_object,   // observing pointer
                  size_t sizeof_object,
                  size_t number_of_objects);
```

You can, of course, pass the elements of a `std::vector` to such a function

```
std::vector<some_type> my_vec;
/* ... fill vector */
C_style_func(my_vec.data(), sizeof(some_type), my_vec.size());
```

The only potential problem with such usage is if the `C_style_func` remembers its first argument for later usage by, say, another function of the same library *and* you alter that pointer by, for example, deleting or altering the `std::vector my_vec`.

Answer (score 0):

If your used `new ANYTYPE[]` to allocate an array you must use `delete []` to delete the array.

Somebody might argue that the `[]` isn't necessary in some C++ compilers when the array elements doesn't have a destructor. But you should let the compiler to make this decision.

If you want to change the size of the array by adding or removing elements you should use the std::vector class template.

Comment: I never mentioned anywhere wanting to add or remove elements. I simply want to avoid dynamically allocating arrays whereever possible, so I can control how they are allocated and destructed.

The class has a vector passed into it, which I am then converting to an array for usage - the DirectX API doesn't appear to accept vectors as arguments, instead opting for an array pointer and its size as two separate parameters. My question was essentially does it know how big the array allocation is, or do I have to specify the size?

Comment: It's not true that omitting `[]` from `delete` will simply forget to call the destructor: it's undefined behavior and anything can happen. On old VC++ compilers (and may be current one too) indeed the effect was just skipping destructors but for example g++ crashes immediately.